# How can I configure Identity Server to correctly validate JWT tokens after an Azure App Slot Switch?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, identityserver4

I have a core hosted API which uses IdentityServer and issues JwtBearer tokens to my desktop based client. This is generally working and I can log in and use the application as expected.

However, when using Azure Deployment Slots I run into problems due to the Issuer validation.

When swapping slots, azure doesn't swap the running code, but rather just swaps the pointing urls so that a warmed up running app is ready to serve requests immediately. However, the Identity Server implemenation seems to keep a reference to the OLD slot URL and use this as part of the Issuer Validation.

This means that once the slots are swapped, not only are all the clients effectively logged out (which is bad enough), but then when the client logs in again the token that the Identity Server supplies isn't even valid becuase it's got the wrong URI for the issuer.

This results in the error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler:
> IdentityServerJwtBearer was not authenticated. Failure message:
> IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer:
> 'https://my-app-name.azurewebsites.net'. Did not match:
> validationParameters.ValidIssuer:
> 'https://my-app-name-deployment.azurewebsites.net' or
> validationParameters.ValidIssuers: 'null'.

I have tried to disable Issuer Validation by doing this in the setup:

```
     services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
        })
        .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

However this doesn't seem to make any difference. Am I setting this variable in the wrong place? Are there other settings that need to be also configured as well as this to bypass this check?

I have also tried setting the list of ValidIssuers to include both 'https://my-app-name.azurewebsites.net' and 'https://my-app-name-deployment.azurewebsites.net' in the hopes that either one would be accepted and allow tokens to be validated by either slot, but again this seems to make no difference.

Alternatively, Is there a way to pervent IdentityServer caching the Issuer Url - or a way to flush that cache without restarting the application? Currently once the slots are swapped the only way I can get the desktop application to access the API is to restart the API application and then log in again aftwards (just logging out and logging in still results in a token that the server cannot validate, even though the server just issued it).

I feel like I must be missing something glaringly obvious, but I can't see what it is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure the IdentityServer JWT Bearer you can use a configure call:

```
    services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(IdentityServerJwtConstants.IdentityServerJwtBearerScheme,
        options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
        });
```

This way it the ValidateIssuer flag is set on the IdentityServerJwt rather than the original code which set up a new JwtBearer which was entirely seperate from the IdentityServer one.

Once the configuration is being set on the correct service it is also possible to use the array of ValidIssuers to include the Asure Slot Urls that should be accepted.